# Calculate the time complexity of the following function

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

How do I calculate the time complexity of the following function?

```
int Compute (int n)
{
   int j = 0;
   int i = 0;
   while (i<=n)
   {
       i = 2*j + i + 1;
       j++;
   }
   return j-1;
}
```

Now, I know that the loop has O(n) time complexity, but in this case `i` grows in a much faster rate. Taking this iteration by iteration I found out that, for every m-th iteration `i = m^2`. But I'm still confused how to calculate Big-O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the values of i and j for a few iterations:

```
i=1
j=1

i=4
j=2

i=9
j=3

i=16
j=4
```

and so on. By mathematical induction we can prove that i takes square values: `( 2*n + n^2 + 1 = (n+1)^2 )`

Since we loop only while i<=n and since i takes the vales 1, 2^2, 3^2,..., k^2 <=n, it means that we stop when i=k goes over sqrt(n). Hence the complexity seems to be O(k) which means O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: I think `O(sqrt(n) - 2) = O(sqrt(n))` is correct. But `we stop when i<=n` should be `i > n`.

Comment: I found the pattern too but couldn't find the connection. Thanks for clarifying!